# How to get MediaElement.DroppedFramesPerSecond properly?

Tags: c#, silverlight, mediaelement

How to properly use `MediaElement.DroppedFramesPerSecond`? I dont know how to get dropped frames when its updated. There is no event associated with frame dropped. I have to create a timer to manually query frame dropped. its not elegant but how can i be sure the timer works correctly?

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.droppedframespersecond%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> Gets the number of frames per second being dropped by the media.

```
public double DroppedFramesPerSecond
{
    get
    {
        return (double)base.GetValue(MediaElement.DroppedFramesPerSecondProperty);
    }
}
```

[MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms611595%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class looks like it gets information like frames per second, dropped frames, etc. You should look at [this project](https://slextensions.codeplex.com/).

Comment: did you ever used droppedframespersecond? maybe im unable to explain the problem properly. yeah, you do get droppedframespersecond value by querying the property. what im trying to get here is, when the frame is drop, i want to know how much. naturally, one would use binding to get updated property. unfortunately, binding the property will result in one time binding. not usefull at all. maybe the problem is better explained here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightmedia/thread/4168fe7e-db62-4f03-ac34-8ba500022835 .

Comment: @publicENEMY Sorry but I never use droppedframespersecond before. Maybe you should ask another question?